# Why is this 'Label' a field?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, properties, field

Im currently working myself trough a Xamarin Book. There you can see this Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BookCode

{
    public class Greetings : ContentPage
{
    public Greetings()
    {
        Label label;

        label = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

        Content = label;

           SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;


        void OnPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            label.Text = String.Format("{0} \u00D7 {1}", Width, Height);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And in an explanation of the code you can read this:

"Instead, the event handler accesses the Label element (conveniently saved as a field) to display the Width and Height properties of the page. The Unicode character in the String.Format call is a times (×) symbol."

My current knowledge of fields and properties is basically this:

```
public class ClassName
{
private string field;

public string property {get {return field;} set {field = value;} }
}
```

I dont understand why the Label element is saved as a field. Could it be saved as something else?

Comment: It's not saved as a field, it's a local variable.

Comment: That is pretty clearly a typo (given it is used inside `OnPageSizeChanged` and thus won't compile). `Label label;` should be declared outside the constructor for that code to compile.

Comment: Let's suppose that we fix the code so that `label` is indeed a field (which is clearly what was intended by the author). Your question is now pertinent. So what's the answer? Only the author knows for sure, but if I had to guess I'd say that it's so that the code handling `OnPageSizeChanged` is somewhat decoupled from the inherited `Content` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is *not* a field. Fields are [members on a class or struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). This label is just a local variable.

The book is wrong.

You can make it a field or property obviously by moving the definition of the label to the class level.